# How do I change what version of GCC Xcode uses?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

Currently, I am trying to compile Imprudence, a third party viewer for the Linden-Lab owned Second Life. I have gotten everything set up and I am now in Xcode. When I click on the Build And Run button, I get an error after a little bit stating that GCC 4.2 is not compatible with the Mac OS X 10.4 SDK.

I have tried changing the Active Architecture in Xcode to x86_64, i386, and ppc. None of these options have changed anything. I am running Mac OS X 10.6.4 and Xcode version 3.2.3. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening? Thank you!

Comment: You're linking against the 10.4 SDK. Changing the architecture doesn't change what SDK you're linking against, which is why that doesn't fix the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodebuildsettings.html

Basically, you need to go to the "Build" tab on the info window, and change the compiler version.

Edit: Seems like your problem is the SDK you're linking against not the compiler version. Fortunately, you can change the SDK version from the same panel I talked about.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! This solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the compiler setting in the "Build" pane in the project's info panel. You can set both the targeted version and the compiler. These settings will cascade to each target, or can be overridden on a target-by-target basis using the same pane in the target's info panel. The base SDK for the project is set in a popup on the "General" pane of the project's info panel.