# Mac osx LION :python cxfreeze installation error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, gcc, osx-lion, cx-freeze

Tried to build cx_Freeze version 4.2.3 using python 3.2.2 in my
Mac osx lion 10.7.4 with XCODE 4.5.1

command to build cxfreeze : env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" python3 setup.py build

Following error occurred, Hope someone have experienced or knows how to fix this.

> adding base module named token
>   adding base module named tokenize
>   adding base module named traceback
>   adding base module named types
>   adding base module named warnings
>   adding base module named weakref
>   running build
>   running build_py
>   running build_ext
>   building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
>   gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c source/util.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-3.2/source/util.o
>   In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/Python.h:73,from source/util.c:6:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/bytearrayobject.h:9:20: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
>   error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

gcc 4.2 doesn't have stdarg.h. Switch to 4.0. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562310/how-do-i-change-what-version-of-gcc-xcode-uses) explains how to switch the version of gcc used by XCode.